# Which BASIC-like language has "ENDIF", "DIM ... OF" to declare arrays, and a double slash for comments?

Tags: basic

My mom found some old source code that she wrote for a course around the year 1983. I've tried to identify the language that is used, but have come up empty-handed. It seemed to be BASIC at first, but I haven't been able to find a version of BASIC matching this syntax. I also don't know what computer the code was written on.

I've transcribed the source code (which was originally on an ancient print-out) exactly as it was written below:

```
0010 // PROGRAM LAVET AF LOTTE OG METTE
0020 DIM NAVN$ OF 20
0030 INPUT "INDTAST NAVN   ":NAVN$
0040 PRINT "NAVN   ";NAVN$
0050 INPUT "INDTAST ALDER   ":ALDER
0060 IF ALDER<16 THEN
0070   PRINT "DUER IKKE   ";ALDER
0080 ELSE
0090   IF ALDER>16 THEN
0100     PRINT "GOD NOK   ";ALDER
0110     INPUT "INDTAST HØJDE   ":HØJDE
0120     IF HØJDE<1.80 THEN
0130       PRINT "SKIP HAM   ";HØJDE
0140     ELSE
0150       IF HØJDE>1.80 THEN
0160         PRINT "UDEMÆRKET   ";HØJDE
0170         INPUT "INDTAST HÅRFARVE RØD=1,BRUN=2,LYS=3,SORT=4 ":HÅRFARVE
0180         IF HÅRFARVE<2 THEN
0190           PRINT "YTTTT ";HÅRFARVE
0200         ELSE
0210           IF HÅRFARVE>1 THEN
0220             PRINT "FLOT FYR   ";HÅRFARVE
0230             INPUT "INDTAST KROPSBYGNING V-FORMET=1,IKKE V-FORMET=2":KROPSBYGNING
0240             IF KROPSBYGNING>1 THEN
0250               PRINT "HAM KAN DU IKKE VÆRE BEKENDT AT FØLGES MED";KROPSBYGNING
0260             ELSE
0270               IF KROPSBYGNING<2 THEN
0280                 PRINT "HAM KAN DU VÆRE STOLT AF";KROPSBYGNING
0290               ENDIF
0300             ENDIF
0310           ENDIF
0320         ENDIF
0330       ENDIF
0340     ENDIF
0350   ENDIF
0360 ENDIF
0370 END
```

The oddities are:

- The comment at line 0010 using a double slash instead of the `REM` keyword.
- The `OF` keyword used in line 0020 when declaring an array with `DIM`.
- The `ENDIF` keyword instead of `END IF`.
- The assignation of variables without any keywords like `LET`, only appending them to the `INPUT` command with a colon.
- The variable names appended with semicolons after `PRINT`'s.
- The allowed use of the foreign characters Æ, Ø and Å.
- Possibly others that I haven't identified.

Other information that could possibly help:

- She claims that the course was sponsored by IBM (but the code doesn't seem to match any IBM BASIC I could find.)
- She claims that the code ran without issue, when it was tested for the course.

It's possible that it's an esoteric BASIC version made specifically for this one course, but I somehow doubt it. Excited to see what you all can make of this.

(And yes, if you know Danish, the program itself is super silly.)

Comment: One suspects that "Æ, Ø and Å" were not _foreign_ characters to the author (and the language).

Comment: Ok, I'll bite: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27834/which-computer-language-was-the-first-with-comments

Comment: @JonCuster Also quite likely that they were made using ISO-646-DK

Comment: By the way, the input and print syntax is not that strange, many BASIC implementations had that.

Comment: @Raffzahn I can confirm that.

Comment: Almost everything in here, *except* the comment "//" was legal in different versions of BASIC that I was aware of at the time.  But I don't know of any version that allowed ***all*** of them.  (VAX BASIC and/or BASIC-Plus-2 in particular allowed almost everything except the comment form, the "OF" and the ENDIF without the space.

Comment: Re, "The allowed use of the foreign characters Æ, Ø and Å" I wouldn't count that for much. Local variants of a programming language were commonplace once upon a time. I took a class once where I was required to write Algol-60 programs, but our only way to input the programs was via IBM 026 Keypunch. The character set was limited to upper-case letters, digits, and ten punctuation characters. The compiler was modified accordingly. ISTR, for example, that we used `$` instead of `;` as a statement separator, and we used something like modern C's _trigraphs_ for certain other characters.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

My guess is that this is [COMAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMAL), which was available on the IBM PC. Notably:

1. COMAL was developed in Denmark.
2. COMAL was based on BASIC (and possibly Pascal).
3. COMAL uses the `DIM variable OF x` format, which is how I found it: I assumed a common variable and searched on “DIM A$ OF”, which produced [an article in COMAL Today](https://archive.org/stream/COMAL_Today_Issue_05_1984_Dec_21/COMAL_Today_Issue_05_1984_Dec_21_djvu.txt) from 1984, “celebrating COMALs 10th anniversary”.
4. COMAL is also a structured language, encouraging indentation of code.
5. COMAL was used in 1983 in educational settings (and may still be today).

You may also find [Update on COMAL: A SuperBASIC](https://www.atarimagazines.com/compute/issue54/132_1_Update_On_COMAL_A_SuperBASIC.php) interesting, describing its use on Commodore machines and praising it as an easy BASIC for beginners with the power of structured Pascal. The Internet Archive has the [Commodore 64 Manual for COMAL-80](https://archive.org/details/comal-80-for-the-commodore-64/page/n141/), and on page 141 you can see the use of double slashes for comments.

COMAL-80 was a version of COMAL available on the IBM PC at the time; you can see its name and the year 1984 [in this image](https://archive.org/details/comal-80). Ingvar Gratte’s [Starting with COMAL](https://archive.org/details/starting-with-comal/mode/2up) is a tutorial written with COMAL-80 (on a Commodore) as the starting point, and you may also find the COMAL-80 Standardization Group’s 1985 [COMAL Kernel: Syntax & Semantics](http://datamuseum.dk/w/images/d/d5/KR_COMAL80_Kernel_Syntax_and_Semantics_Apr_1985.pdf) useful as a reference.

Comment: Thank you! This has been doing my head in. What an interesting language I had no clue existed!

Comment: Wiki article also links to [this PDF](http://datamuseum.dk/w/images/d/d5/KR_COMAL80_Kernel_Syntax_and_Semantics_Apr_1985.pdf) which has full syntax including `//` remarks. Impressed you found this so fast.

Comment: I personally remember the COMAL cartridge for C64 being used at school. IIRC, we used to add cool stuff to the EEPROM in it

Comment: That was my immediate guess.  We were taught programming in COMAL at school in the mid-90s on old (even at the time) BBC computers.  I think they changed a couple of years later.

Comment: COMAL was available for the BBC Micros

Comment: COMAL on Apple II was the government mandated platform for computer science classes here in Ireland in the early 80s.

Answer (score 15):

Comments are in Danish, so this is Comal, and most likely Comal80 which was what was taught in Danish schools at that time.  I cut my teeth on the Regnecentral version - which was robust but slow - but others existed.  If your mom can remember any characteristics about the machines they used, we can probably identify it.

[image]

You may find the emulator at http://www.jbox.dk/rc702/emulator.shtm interesting as disk images with RC Comal80 is available.

Comal80 is a nice teaching language as it has the interactivity of BASIC with elements of structured programming.   A nice stepping stone to PolyPascal/Turbo Pascal.